# replacing multiple spaces with comma in unix

Tags: bash, unix, sed, tr

I have a file with the following data:

```
1               abcd               hello world               5000
```

(note: there are 15 spaces between each word and "hello world" is a single entry with one space in between)

I have to replace the 15 spaces with a single comma(,). the single space between "hello and "world" should remain as it is.

I have tried various combinations of sed and tr command but nothing is working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple consecutive white spaces with one comma in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23106621/608639)

Answer (score 5):

This is a job for `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/ {15}/,/g' file
1,abcd,hello world,5000
```

or, without the `-r` flag that allows extended regexp:

```
$ sed 's/ \{15\}/,/g' file
1,abcd,hello world,5000
```

This says: get 15 spaces and replace them with a comma. Smaller amount of spaces won't be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

just an improvement really since you already have an correct answer:

This will replace any sequence of at least 2 consecutive spaces with a ','

```
sed -r 's/ {2,}/,/g' file
1,abcd,hello world,5000
```

This will allow for "hello world" or any other string which uses a single space as separator and also saves you the trouble of having to make sure you have exactly 15 spaces.